# How to make a form like properties window in visual studio?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `TreeView` object and I need when a `node` of `treeview` is selected, `form` is shown in definite location (properties of the `node`), and when another `node` is selected, the `form` changes. When no node is selected, the `form` disappear. `Form` contains only `ListView` object. I need something like properties window in visual studio.

**The problem I have now:**

`Form` appear randomly, in wrong location, I need it to be shown in definite location in another `form`.

After each mouse down event, appear a new `form`, but I need there will be only one `form` (or old disappear - new appear)

When no nodes are selected, the `form` doesn't disappear.

How can I solve this problems, or maybe there is a better solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I think you are seeking is the PropertyGrid control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx

It is a very deep and complex control, but can give amazing result.

Answer (score 0):

About
    After each mouse down event, appear a new form, but I need there will be
    only one form (or old disappear - new appear)
My solution:

Add to Form class a static variable Form frm;
Add to Form class a static function

```
//Create new form if not yet created
//Or return instance of opened form which can update by new parameters
public static Form Instance()
{
    if (Form.frm = null)
        Form.frm = new Form();
    return Form.frm;
}
```

Then create all new forms only through this static function. Create overload functions for this static function if you want open different instances of Form.

And of course remember dispose static Form.frm object on  closing form

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes for showing your form :

```
 private Form2 f2;    

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (f2 == null) {
       f2 = new Form2();
       f2.FormClosed += delegate { f2 = null; };
       f2.Show();
    }
    else {
       f2.Activate();
    }
}
```